# System.Web.UI Namespace doesn't exist

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces

I'm trying to include System.Web.UI to my solution

[image: 1]

I've looked at similar question, saying I have to add reference - I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 from 2019, and in 2019 it was clear where this fix was placed. In 2022 I've yet to find that function to add reference to a solution.

In 2019 it was solved like this:
Go to Menu Project --> Add Reference --> Chose Framework --> Choose System.Web dll and click OK.
But how is this achieved in 2022?

Can anyone help - either with another fix on the namespace issue, or how to add reference in VS 2022?

Thanks

Comment: What replace the System.Web.UI Namespace in .NET 6? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70444489/196526